# show confirmation message while removing item from cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a confirmation message when customer will try to remove an item from cart, I've googled this but am not able to find any solution.can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used 
onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure, You want to delete this resource?');"

Comment: echo "<td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>x</a></td><tr>"; //use double quotes for js inside php!